# Replacing characters at specific positions in strings in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, plsql, replace, substring

I'm trying to write a function that can decode a message by switching pairs of characters around.

Say I have the `message hello!` which, when encoded, turns into `ehll!o`. 
Is there an existing function in `Oracle` that lets me `replace characters` at specified positions with other characters of my choosing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use regex that looks like a tits:

```
regexp_replace(string, '(.)(.)', '\2\1')
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/072fdd/1)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be looking for SubStr() I believe. Possibly Translate() or Replace().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply mask few characters from a particular position, you could like below

```
SUBSTR(field_name,1,4) || 'XXXX' || SUBSTR(field_name,LENGTH(field_name)-4,LENGTH(field_name))
as field_name
```

If the field values is **0007125009300**
Output will be **0007XXXX09300**